# How to assign a particlualr color to a <Li> element which belongs to a same group

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list like this.

```
   <ul>
     <li id="1">saurabh</li>
     <li id="2">sanjay</li>
     <li id="3">blah</li>
     <li id="4" parentID="3">chacha<li>
   </ul>
```

Suppose now I add another element to a list. I want to add a color to this special element. I will have a list of some predefined 10 colors. So I will take the first color and delete it from the list. So the next time when i take a color the first one is not there.Now this special element can have children also. So all the children will have same color of the parent.

How can I achieve this in java script?

Comment: Why JavaScript, shouldnt that be possible with pure HTML/CSS?

Comment: ya anything is welcome. Tell me a way please! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. It uses the CSS3 syntax for `nth-of-type`. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/2FAcS/

CSS Markup

```
ul#myList > li:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
}
ul#myList > li:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: green;
}
ul#myList > li:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: blue;
}
```

HTML Markup:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>first item</li>
    <li>second item</li>
    <li>
        <p>third item, which has an embedded list</p>
        <ul>
            <li>first subitem</li>
            <li>second subitem</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The children of the third item all have the same color.

Comment: +1 This is the better choice if his list is prerendered. Itll work even if its not.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/UgAn4/1/)**

```
var ulist = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
    colors = ['red', 'blue', '#eee313'];

function addListItem(list){
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.innerHTML = 'test item';
    if(colors.length > 0){
        listItem.style.background = colors[0];
        list.appendChild(listItem);
        colors.shift();
    }
}

setInterval(function(){addListItem(ulist)}, 2000);
```

**[Live Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/UgAn4/2/)** - Shows how the parent `li`'s color will be transferred to any children.

Comment: I mean if "blah" is red then all it's child like "item1","item2"....must be red......

Comment: They would be, youd add a list to the LI that has blah in it.

Comment: can you show me a live demo of that also. I don't know HTML and css.

Comment: added a live demo 2, how are you adding more list items? Via javascript? If you aren't adding items in real time then @Alp answer is the better one.

Comment: actually in my scenerio I have list and subchildren. The subchildren look as like a normal <li>. So i can't make a distinguish because both parent and child are using the same CSS class.

Comment: You should check out my answer, anything you need should be in there. Write a command if you still have problems.